# Deleting attachments using Thunderbird + Owl/Active Sync Mail account does not work

Tags: thunderbird, exchange, activesync, thunderbird-addon

I was forced to change from IMAP to Active Sync for an Exchange Mail server. While everything worked great with IMAP, since using Owl/Active Sync/Exchange, deleting a mail *attachment* deletes the *whole* message.

When I do "get messages", it sometimes *re-appears* (whole message, incl. the "deleted" attachment. The problem is, that the account size is limitded and we need to delete unnecessary attachments, but not the whole mail.

Is this a known bug, is there a known workaround? I could not find it on Bugzilla, just want to make sure not to miss something else how to prevent this behaviour. Should I file it as a bug?